# How to take values of a unique ID and apply to all their IDs

Tags: python, excel-formula

I'm using excel to try and apply unique ID values to a list of duplicated IDs.

So for example:

```
listID    unique ID    uniqueID value
a         a             100
a         b             200
a      
b
b
```

How can I produce the following from the information above:

```
listID    listID values     uniqueID    uniqueID values
a         100               a           100
a         100               b           200
a         100                            
b         200                                
b         200
```

What is the best formula to produce the results above, or should I try in another program such as python?

Comment: Learn about `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks, I got exactly what I was trying to do with vVLOOKUP.